# Параллельные запросы на PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, requests, qthread

Какие есть способы организовать параллельное выполнение session.get(url) в PyQt?
Я использую QThread, но requests каким-то образом ставит запросы в очередь. Т.е. начинается выполнение одновременно, а заканчивается в порядке очереди.

Для чего мне это.

Если это важно, то я одновременно хочу прошерстить множество страниц сайта и забрать с них нужную мне информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В pyqt для этого есть менеджер запросов `QNetworkAccessManager`

Небольшой пример. После выполнения в логе можно посмотреть в каком порядке завершались запросы

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkReply, QNetworkRequest
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl,QDateTime,QByteArray
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.log = QTextEdit(self)
        self.log.setGeometry(10,10,450,300)
        self.button = QPushButton('push me',self)
        self.button.setGeometry(10, 350, 100, 100)
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pushbtn())
        # Создадим менеджер
        self.qnam = QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        # ответ будем ловить по сигналу завершения запроса
        self.qnam.finished.connect(self.req_finished)

    def req_finished(self, rep):
        # проверяем была ли ошибка
        if rep.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
            data = rep.readAll() # читаем данные
            data = f'{len(data)} bytes readed'
        else:
            data = f'ERROR: {rep.errorString()}'
        self.log.append(f'{QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz")} finished {rep.request().rawHeader(b"My-Request-ID").data().decode()}: {data}')

        rep.deleteLater()

    def pushbtn(self):
        # при нажатии на кнопку создадим несколько запросов
        for i in range(20):
            req = QNetworkRequest(QUrl('https://yandex.ru'))
            # в хэдерах будет заголовок с номером запроса по порядку 
            req.setRawHeader(b"My-Request-ID", QByteArray(str(i).encode()))
            self.log.append(f'{QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz")} start {i}')
            # добавляем запрос в менеджер
            self.qnam.get(req)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```